# How to fetch a specific data from a json format string to populate recyclerview?

Tags: android, json, fetch, implementation

today I am having problem understanding how to extract specific values from this json string.

Mind you, I intend to populate a recyclerview with datas taken from here.

Let me first show you the format of the json string：

```
[
{
"recipe_filter":"Veg",
"recipe_array":[
{
"recipe_name":"Nimki",
"recipe_image":"nimki",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"2 Hours",
"recipe_prep_steps":"Steps",
"recipe_ingredients":"123456"
},
{
"recipe_name":"Palang Paneer",
"recipe_image":"palang_paneer",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"1.5 Hours",
"recipe_prep_steps":"Steps",
"recipe_ingredients":"12"
}
]
},
{
"recipe_filter":"Non Veg",
"recipe_array":[
{
"recipe_name":"Chicken Rezala",
"recipe_image":"chicken_rezala",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"2 Hours",
"recipe_prep_steps":"1234567",
"recipe_ingredients":"123"
},
{
"recipe_name":"Omu Rice",
"recipe_image":"omu_rice",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"1 Hour",
"recipe_prep_steps":"123456",
"recipe_ingredients":"12"
}
]
},
{
"recipe_filter":"",
"recipe_array":[
{
"recipe_name":"",
"recipe_image":"",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"",
"recipe_prep_steps":"",
"recipe_ingredients":""
},
{
"recipe_name":"",
"recipe_image":"",
"isFavourite":false,
"isInCookList":false,
"recipe_prep_time":"",
"recipe_prep_steps":"",
"recipe_ingredients":""
}
]
}
]
```

I want to fetch data in the recyclerview based on whether the recipe_filter is veg or non veg.

So guys, please give me pointers on how to fetch only the recipe_array value, veg or non veg recipes based on the recipe_filter value in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First get value of your "recipe_filter" then after compare with your value Please check below code:

First Create json response POJO class:

```
public class RecipeResponse {

@SerializedName("recipe_filter")
@Expose
private String recipeFilter;
@SerializedName("recipe_array")
@Expose
private List<RecipeArray> recipeArray = null;

public String getRecipeFilter() {
return recipeFilter;
}

public void setRecipeFilter(String recipeFilter) {
this.recipeFilter = recipeFilter;
}

public List<RecipeArray> getRecipeArray() {
return recipeArray;
}

public void setRecipeArray(List<RecipeArray> recipeArray) {
this.recipeArray = recipeArray;
}

}
```

After getting successful json response Compare your recipe_filter value with veg or non veg.:

```
public void doRecipeSuccess(RecipeResponse mRecipeResponse){
    if(mRecipeResponse.recipeFilter.equal("veg")){
// Write down veg code.
}else if(mRecipeResponse.recipeFilter.equal("non veg")){
// Write down non veg code.
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along the line of using json querying to fetch the data accordingly

Comment: @BodhisatwaChakraborty Also use Retrofit for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Create POJO classes  and then use GSON library [a link](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/)

Answer (score 0):

## Try This

> Main Activity

- declare this on above of oncreate method

  ```
  RecyclerView rv_myCart;
  Adapter adapter;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> all_list=new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- in your on create method use this code

  ```
  rv_myCart=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_completepurchase);
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
  rv_myCart.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
  rv_myCart.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
  adapter = new Adapter(all_list);
  rv_myCart.setAdapter(adapter);
      try {
          JSONArray json=new JSONArray(strjson);
  //                Log.e(TAG, "json: "+json );
          for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
          {
              HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
              JSONObject jsonobject=json.getJSONObject(i);
  //                    Log.e(TAG, "recipe_filter: "+jsonobject.getString("recipe_filter") );
              hashMap.put("recipe_filter",jsonobject.getString("recipe_filter"));
              JSONArray recipe_array=jsonobject.getJSONArray("recipe_array");
         //                    Log.e(TAG, "recipe_array: "+recipe_array );
              for (int j=0;j<recipe_array.length();j++)
              {
                  JSONObject object=recipe_array.getJSONObject(j);
        //                        Log.e(TAG, "recipe_name: "+object.getString("recipe_name") );
                  hashMap.put("recipe_name",object.getString("recipe_name") );
              }
              all_list.add(hashMap);
          }
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.e(TAG, "e: "+e );
      }
  ```

> Adapter Class

- Declare this in your adapter class

  ```
   private List<HashMap<String,String>> myCartList;
  ```
- your adapter method

  ```
   public Adapter(List<HashMap<String,String>> myCartList) {
  this.myCartList= myCartList;
  }
  ```
- in your onBindViewHolder method

  ```
  HashMap<String,String> hashmap=myCartList.get(position);
  if (hashmap.get("recipe_filter").equals("Veg"))
  {
      //todo when recipe_filter is veg
  }
  else
  {
      //// TODO: when recipe_filter is nonveg 
  }
  ```

**Note**:-still facing problem download full code from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4heJhgwlwgoZVNwb3ZYNHpJcTg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

In your comment to Vishal Patolia's answer, you mention JSON querying. On Android without any libraries, an option for accessing JSON data is using the [org.json](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) library bundled within the Android Platform. While you can't-do a direct single query get to the data you want, you can get there programmatically querying your way towards your data.

Here is how you would get the recipe_array for "veg":

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString); 
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    if (json.getJSONObject(i).getString("recipe_filter").equals("veg")) {
        // Here is one recipe_array for veg
        JSONArray someVegArrayData = json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("recipe_array");
    }
}
```

I recommend you go with Vishal's answer and use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library or something similar to parse your JSON.

Comment: Thank you for recommend my answer.